# List with array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have such construction

```
List<int[]> nodeIds = new List<int[]>();
```

Can I get each element from `int[]`?And how I can do it ?

Comment: learn some programming basics, before asking such questions

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
foreach(int[] items in nodeIds)
  foreach(int item in items)
    // do something with item
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) method to flatten sequences into one sequence:

```
IEnumerable<int> allIds = nodeIds.SelectMany(x => x);
```

UPDATE: If you need only unique ids in resulting sequence, then apply also [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) after flattering sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `List` of `int[]` so what you need to do is to get each element of each item in the `List`. You will have to use nested cycle for that - one over the list and second over the array of the list item currently considered.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
foreach(var nodeId in nodeIds)
{
    foreach(var id in nodeId)
    {
        //do stuff with id
    }
}
```

or

```
nodeIds[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all integers from all arrays in the list, you can use the `SelectMany` method of `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<int> allIDs = nodeIds.SelectMany(a => a);
```

You can enumerate the result using `foreach` or perform aggregation on the results, etc.